# distribution of $Y= \exp(-X^2)$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a question about distribution functions. 
Assume that $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. I want to compute the mean and variance of $Y = \exp(-\frac{X^2}{2h^2})$ analytically. What is the solution?

Comment: I want to find the mean and variance of $Y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}h}\exp(-\frac{X^2}{2h^2})$

Answer (score 4):

**Mean**:

You integrate $y=e^{-x^2}$ times a Gaussian pdf. Hence, you get an exponential with exponent

$$-x^2-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}=-\frac{2\sigma^2x^2+x^2-2\mu x+\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}.$$

By completing the square,

$$2\sigma^2x^2+x^2-2\mu x+\mu^2=(2\sigma^2+1)(x-\frac\mu{2\sigma^2+1})^2-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2+1}.$$

This yields the pdf of a Gaussian of $\sigma'=\frac\sigma{\sqrt{2\sigma^2+1}}$, times the coefficient $e^{\mu^2/(2\sigma^2+1)2\sigma^2}$. The integral is still $1$, provided you adjust for the change of $\sigma$, with the factor $\sigma/\sigma'$.

Hence

$$\overline{y}=\frac1{\sqrt{2\sigma^2+1}}\,e^{\mu^2/(2\sigma^2+1)2\sigma^2}.$$

**Variance**:

Repeat this procedure for $y^2=e^{-2x^2}$, to get

$$\overline{y^2}=\frac1{\sqrt{4\sigma^2+2}}\,e^{\mu^2/(4\sigma^2+1)2\sigma^2}.$$

The final value is

$$\sigma^2_y=\overline{y^2}-\overline y^2.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, but I want to try $Y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}h}\exp(-\frac{X^2}{2h^2})$. so what will be difference?

Comment: @A.S.: Are you sure ? The modified integral is $\propto\exp(-x^2/2\sigma'^2)/\sigma=\sigma'/\sigma\exp(-x^2/2\sigma'^2)/\sigma'$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure. For $\mu=0$, $E(Y)\to 0$ as $\sigma\to \infty$ and for $\mu=0$, $E(Y)=(1+2\sigma^2)^{-1/2}$ for sure.

Comment: @Hamid: if you un-accepted the answer because you wanted more, this isn't really fair.

Comment: @A.S.: yep, stupid me, I wrote $\sigma'/\sigma$ the wrong way.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: I know it isn't fair, but the answer for me is really hard but for you is very simple. I thought I could find the difference, but I couldn't. If you give me the answer, you will make me so happy

Comment: @Hamid: come on, just redo the computation with $x/h$ instead of $x$ where it pertains. "for you is very simple": I don't think I was the one to put the less effort into this.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: you mean I can put $\frac{\mu}{h}$ instead of $\mu$ and $\frac{\sigma^2}{h^2}$ instead of $\sigma^2$ ???

Comment: @Hamid: no, I said you can put $x/h$ instead of $x$ at some place(s). Did I mention $\mu$ or $\sigma$ ??

Comment: @Yves Daoust: I confusing. are you sure about the $\frac{{\sigma}'}{\sigma}$ ???

Comment: @Hamid: read all comments.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: but the final value is OK???

Comment: @Hamid: re-read A.S.'s comments.

Answer (score 1):

The mean of $e^{-X^2}$ is the integral of $e^{-x^2}$ weighted by the density function of $X$ (which is another exponential function). For an analytic expression, notice that the integral now contains a product of two exponentials. Combine the product of exponentials into an exponential of a sum and re-write the resulting exponent as a single negative square (plus a constant).

The variance is the mean of the square of $e^{-X^2}$ minus the square of the mean, so its analytic computation is very similar.

Comment: thank you, but is it possible to write the formula and the results exactly? I highly appreciate you

Comment: See Yves Daoust's reply below and don't forget to upvote the guy for his trouble.